# Lighttpd: Need help in blocking a folder and its files / subdirectories from directly accessing through the URL

Tags: lighttpd

On Lighttpd ver. 1.4.X

I tried using the below example to block the access to the folder "settings" and its contents. But, as I observed, only the folder "settings" will get blocked correctly. But, if I give any filename under it in the browser URL, (Ex: https://mywebsite.com/settings/verysecret.json) it just gets downloaded instead of blocking it. Need your help in properly constructing the pattern to block the access to the "settings" folder and its contents as well.

Example:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/settings/" {
     url.access-deny = ("")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not loading [mod_access](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/mod_access).

Try adding `server.modules += ("mod_access")` to your lighttpd.conf